# PowerPoint presentation played in windows store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, powerpoint, windows-store-apps, office-interop

I need to play a PowerPoint presentation embedded as an asset in a windows store app.
I downloaded the Visual Studio Tools for Visual Studio 2012 and tried to use the old school Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint package but I stumbled upon the following error:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} using CoCreateInstanceFromApp
>   failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please
>   make sure your COM object is in the allowed list of
>   CoCreateInstanceFromApp

So it seems that windows store apps cannot call these types of COM objects.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx

Is there any API available for windows store apps to show a pptx?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no API to show a pptx within a Windows Store app.

Some workarounds might be:

- Launch the pptx in PowerPoint (outside of your Windows Store app) from your app.  Here is [how to launch the default app for a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452687.aspx) (PowerPoint is the default app for a .pptx).
- Convert the pptx slides to images (either beforehand if this is a static PowerPoint deck you are showing, or call a webservice that can do this if you need to support receiving and displaying new PowerPoint decks)